# Automatic fade in fade out of divs contain in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need a small help from all of you . 
I have a list in which multiple div is present. Each list has 3 divs inside it where the first div of every list is an image. I need to fade in fade out the first div of each list.

Below is my code.

```
    <input type="radio" id="control1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="control1"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="control2" name="controls"/>
    <label for="control2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="control3" name="controls"/>
    <label for="control3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="control4" name="controls"/>
    <label for="control4"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="control5" name="controls"/>
    <label for="control5"></label>
    <div  class="sliderinner">
        <ul>
             <li>
              <div id ="image1">
               <div class="description">

                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Slideshow Title 3</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li >
               <div id ="image2">
                <div class="description">

                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Laddak</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li>
               <div id ="image3">
                <div class="description">

                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Hangouts</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li>
               <div id="image4">
                <div class="description">

                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Birds</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li  >
               <div id="image5">
                <div class="description">

                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Taj Mahal</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!--slider-->
```

Comment: you mean like a slow infinite blink or from visitor action ?

Comment: Do you mean each list or each list item because if you fade the first div of list item in code above the inner divs's also won't be visible.

Comment: @mdesdev : each list item .. I just need to fade in fade out the div  which has images. div with class description and description-text are for different purpose and I need to keep them ..

Comment: @GCyrillus yes .. a slow infinite action

Comment: @user3092250 Ok do you wanna fade `#image1, #image2, #image3` div's because if that's a case the inner div's `.description, .description-text` can't be visible.

Comment: you need to set an animation

Comment: exactly .. the inner div's (description and description-text) are just like tool tip which displays only on mouse hover of that particular image.

Comment: Could you please provide with any sample ..

Comment: @user3092250 see below in answers

Comment: Hello everyone , thanks for giving your valuable time for my question .. 
Though I didn't get what I exactly want but all of you have helped me a lot with your code specially doing it in jsfiddle , I have found an alternative to my requirement . As instead of fading in and out I am sliding the images automatically and stopping it on mouse over.

Anyways thanks a lot again .. Specially to http://stackoverflow.com/users/2666313/mdesdev and 
http://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/gcyrillus.. Both of your answers are correct .. but due to some reason they won't get applicable in my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<edit>
```

animation + delay increased for each boxes : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qAjod/

```
</edit>
```

---

here is an example :

```
div {
  animation: fdio  1s infinite;
  background:gray;
}
@keyframes fdio {
  50% {opacity:0;}
}
```

for : `<div> text </div>`

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iBJpC/)**

---

*do not forget to add vendor-prefix or use a script to add them automaticly*

Comment: Hi i actually forgot to mention that in my code only one image displays in screen at a time ... My requirement is that on page load image1 gets loaded then after some time image2 fades in then image3 fades ..then at last again image1 fade in . please note that these images are in div

Comment: @user3092250 okay, so it could be like this , using nth-child and delay http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dbcuA

Comment: @user3092250 on on top of each others ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qAjod/ if you want one at the time

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me out but I guess I could not make you understand about my requirement. I am working on a image gallery where only one images displays on screen at a time in same postion.. I have 3 images , I just need to fade in the 2nd image at the same place and the first image must fade out that time then after some time 2nd image fades out and 3rd image fades in .. This is what I need .. The image position is same .

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>            
<li>
              <div id="image1" class="abc">
               <div class="description">
                     <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Slideshow Title 3</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
               <div id="image2" class="abc">
                <div class="description">
                     <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Laddak</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
               <div id="image3" class="abc">
                <div class="description">
                     <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Hangouts</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </li>
</ul>



 setInterval(function(){ $(".abc").fadeToggle("slow");},4000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x73z9/2/

Comment: Its not working..  <div  class="sliderinner">
            <ul>
                 <li>
                  <div id="image1" class="fade">
                   <div class="description">
 
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Slideshow Title 3</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </li> 
i did this ..:(

Comment: what is question you when want to fadin fadout your div

Comment: please see the fiddle may be it's helpfull to yoy

Comment: I just want to fadein and fade out the first div of every list item (this div contains image) infinitely with a transition of 4-5 secs.

Comment: than it's working fine please see fiddle link and give time 4000

Comment: hiii.. thanks for this .. but my issue is that I have a multiple div as you can see in my code .. and using your code it not getting toggle ... :( please help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Hi i actually forgot to mention that in my code only one image displays in screen at a time .. So when I am using your code the issue is that only the first image is fading in and out ..

Comment: hey sorry I can't put my full code right now it will be against my company policy ..

I explain you in breif. I am working on a image gallery where only one images displays on screen at a time in same postion.. I have 3 images , I just need to fade in the 2nd image at the same place and the first image must fade out that time then after some time 2nd image fades out and 3rd image fades in .. This is what I need .. The image position is same

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this :

```
li div:first-child {
  //put css code here
}
```